# How to include CSS file From an HTML helper using section

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I have a custom helper which return some Html and Javascript. I have to include a Css file but I would like to include it into my custom helper.

The helper have to include the css file that it needs.

Is there any solution like this :

**In a view :**

```
@section mySection { 
    <link href="@Url.Content("...")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
}
```

**In my Layout :**

```
@RenderSection("mySection", required: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to just write this in your layout:

```
@RenderSection("ScriptTags", false)
```

Also, it's not going to work if your *View* is a *Partial View*